# Redux saga in shadow dom in multiple tabs, only run once

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

1. I have a platform app in react.
2. I have a small react app which supports **multiple customer tabs** in browser.
3. The platform app embeds the small react app as shadow dom.
4. The small App.js looks like this

```
function App() {
  // create redux store here
  
  // sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);


  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(ACTION) -> 
    saga catch it -> call api -> feed back to reducer -> 
    feed back to ui
  });

  return <div>bla</div>;
}
```

There are lots of examples on the web. They put store + sagaMiddleware.run outside of App.js. **This means only create 1 store and 1 saga middleware**. When App.js is embedded into platform. Say you open multiple tabs, you will have multiple App.js instance, but your store is only 1, so each tab is syncing with other tabs, which we don't want

You can see that I put store + middleware run inside the App.js. That is necessary when embedding.

```
// In this example, we put store and middle ware out side of app, but sitting like a global variable in a file App.js. 

// If you put a console.log  right next to sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga). No matter how many tabs you open, console.log only print once.

// create redux store here
  
// sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(ACTION) -> 
    saga catch it -> call api -> feed back to reducer -> 
    feed back to ui
  });

  return <div>bla</div>;
}
```

The current issue is that when open 1st customer in tab in platform app. Everything is fine. (able to get data via api and display result). When I close 1st tab and open the **same customer** again.

I found that `useEffect` is firing, when same tab is open, but `sagaMiddleware.run` seems not running at all, so it is not able to catch any action.

**Another case** is that I open customer A all good, then I open customer B. `sagaMiddleware.run` seems not running at all. `takeEvery`, etc is not running.

Anyone has any hint?

Comment: I am very surprised to learn that tab shares the same memory space because you say the store is only 1. Moreover, if you use react-redux's Provider element, that normally wrap `<App />`, what do you mean by create store outside App. If you can kindly share the link to the code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem is about the didMount() and the didUpdate() logics ... you need to tell the app about the changes. You can do something like this:

```
const mounted = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mounted.current) {
      // do componentDidMount logic
      mounted.current = true;
    } else {
      // do componentDidUpdate logic
      // create redux store here
      // sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
    }
  });
```

I hope it can help you !

Comment: Another case is that I open customer A all good, then I open customer B. sagaMiddleware.run seems not running at all. takeEvery, etc is not running.